# Application not responding after videoCapture in open cv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am using Qt in ubuntu with C++.
I am reading a video using `VideoCapture` in `openCV`.
But immediately after opening video container my application doesn't respond.

```
char filename[50];
VideoCapture cap;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

ui->setupUi(this);
sprintf(filename,"/media/sf_Shared_with_VM/helicopter_with_stickers.mp4");
cap.open(filename);
printf("\nFile Opened");
```

}

Here file is opened but it didn't print "File opened".

It is a part of a big program where on button click, I have to record raw video and overlay video. Video displaying and storing is working fine. But I want to print "Raw recording" when I press "record raw" button and so for other buttons. But it didn't get printed unless I press it twice or press another button, i.e. it is responding after one button press. I debugged it to `cap.open(filename);`, because I couldn't print "File Opened" just after that.

Comment: Your `filename` is a char buffer or QString ? You should use the QString format function instead of sprintf. In case the `filename` is a char buffer, you use a wrong format of sprintf, it should be sprintf( filename, "%s", "your file ....");

Comment: Thanks, how will it help with my problem?

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the way you are using sprintf. You can ofcourse replace it with `char filename[] = "path to your file"` though.

Comment: Also note that since you are not flushing your output after `printf("\nFile Opened");` - you can't say whether this line of code was executed or not. Replace it with `printf("\nFile Opened\n")` or add `fflush(stdout)` after that line

Comment: Have you tried to print result with http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdebug.html?

Comment: @DmitriiZ. printf("\nFile Opened\n") worked. Use this as the answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't see your last log message because you don't flush your standard output stream.

You can do it either by adding newline after the message `printf("\nFile Opened\n")` or by explicitly calling `fflush(stdout)` after the last `printf`.